# Как в PostgreSQL создавать и работать с двухмерными массивами текста?

Tags: массивы, postgresql, sql

Вопрос в следующем: как создать двухмерный массив текста со структурой:

```
{{'data11','data12',... }, {'data21','data22','data23',... },...}
```

Как из него вытаскивать данные? Способ: `SELECT mas[1][1]`, для того чтобы вытащить 'data11', прокатит?

Как по нему, например, найти 'data12' в `mas[1]` или массив, содержащий 'data23' во всей строке mas?

Как добавлять значение, к примеру, в конец `mas[1]` или новый массив в mas?

Как их удалять - строки из массивов или отдельный массив?

Comment: json подойдёт

Comment: Да, он в принципе не плохой, но его туда-сюда-обратно парсить нужно, а с настоящими массивами проще жить, я так думаю.

Comment: нет.

    update q set json = '[[2,3,4],[5,6,7]]' where id = 24493;

    select json,json->0,json->0->1 from q where id = 24493;
           json          | ?column? | ?column? 
    -----------------+----------+----------
     [[2,3,4],[5,6,7]] | [2,3,4]  | 3

ну и дальше читайте доки. я бы сказал, что всё о чём вы пишете сейчас решается с помощью jsonb, а если и нет то часть задач решать можно решать на уровне приложения.

Comment: А как обновлять? Как я понял, для этого надо пройти все круги ада?

Comment: В мануале PostgreSQL подробно расписано, как работать с массивами: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html